# Como ler essa relação neste diagrama ER?

Tags: banco-de-dados, diagrama

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tendo esse diagrama ER como eu leio a relação entre conta e cliente? 
Eu pensei em ler da seguinte forma "Um cliente pode ter N contas, e uma conta sempre está associada à M clientes" essa forma de leitura está correta para descrever relações M:N?

Comment: Eu entendo que a representação utilizada signifique: Uma conta esta associada a 1 ou mais clientes e um cliente pode estar associado a 0 ou mais contas. Agora me parece estranho que um cliente possa existir sem estar associado a uma conta, mas se é o que está especificado em seus requisitos então é só segui-los.

Comment: Este exemplo também não faz muito sentido para mim, no entanto é o que está presente no livro pelo qual eu estou estudando. Então a minha leitura está parcialmente correta ? Só precisaria descrever melhor a cardinalidade mínima e máxima ?

Comment: Pelo que entendi a linha dupla indica uma obrigatoriedade, ou seja, define a cardinalidade mínima.